# How to extract an object from an array of objects in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a simple json with an array of objects, I managed to extract the record but it comes up with square brackets, and I want just the object.

```js
var res = {
  "totalSize": 3,
  "done": true,
  "records": [{
    "Id": "1",
    "CaseNumber": "1",
    "Subject": "test1"
  }, {
    "Id": "2",
    "CaseNumber": "2",
    "Subject": "test2"
  }, {
    "Id": "3",
    "CaseNumber": "3",
    "Subject": "test3"
  }]
}

var extractedRecord = res.records.slice(0, 1);
```

Desired outcome:

```
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "CaseNumber": "1",
    "Subject": "test1"
  }
```

Actual outcome:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "CaseNumber": "1",
    "Subject": "test1"
  }
]
```

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rpuotbgk/2/).

Comment: Read about [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). And about arrays, [in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and in general.

Comment: Just use `res.records[0]`

Comment: Why was my question downvoted? At least provide some pointers for me to learn for future cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arrray.prototype.slice()`, as its [documention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) states, returns a new array from an original one.

From MDN (my emphasis):

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array
>   into a **new array object** selected from begin to end (end not included)
>   where begin and end represent the index of items in that array. The
>   original array will not be modified.

Knowing this, it's no surprise you're getting an array returned (i.e. your object encased with `[` and `]`). Therefore you just need to extract the only item in it:

```
var extractedRecord = res.records.slice(0, 1)[0];
```

Comment: I accepted this answer and not the others because @Utkanos provided explanations and not just the code. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Just do `res.records.slice(0, 1)[0]`

```js
var res = {"totalSize":3,"done":true,"records":[{"Id":"1","CaseNumber":"1","Subject":"test1"},{"Id":"2","CaseNumber":"2","Subject":"test2"},{"Id":"3","CaseNumber":"3","Subject":"test3"}]}

var extractedRecord = res.records.slice(0, 1)[0];
console.log(extractedRecord);
```

You can also use spread syntax:

```js
var res = {"totalSize":3,"done":true,"records":[{"Id":"1","CaseNumber":"1","Subject":"test1"},{"Id":"2","CaseNumber":"2","Subject":"test2"},{"Id":"3","CaseNumber":"3","Subject":"test3"}]}

var extractedRecord = res.records.slice(0, 1);
console.log(...extractedRecord);
```

Comment: Do you need `.slice()`?

Comment: @axiac no we don't, but answering based on OP context

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.It will works for you.

```js
var res = {"totalSize":3,"done":true,"records":[{"Id":"1","CaseNumber":"1","Subject":"test1"},{"Id":"2","CaseNumber":"2","Subject":"test2"},{"Id":"3","CaseNumber":"3","Subject":"test3"}]}

const data = res.records[0]
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation, otherwise the OP has no way of knowing what they did wrong.

Comment: They did not wrong anything,but this is other way to achieve the answer of question and also getting without slice method.

Comment: This is the only right answer, as in, there is no point of using `slice()` when all you want to do is to access an array element.

Comment: @MichałSadowski yes and no. You are right that this answer shows the shortest route to achieving the desired output. But insofar as the OP expressed confusion about how `slice()` works, it is worth explaining that erroenous thinking.

Comment: @Utkanos true, but it also, I believe, is important to point out how accessing elements of an array should be done.